# Angular APP_INITIALIZER random compiler bug - has anyone else encountered it yet?

Tags: angular

I think I found a bug in Angular, but I am not sure about it, and it actually popped up in an area which I am not very familiar with yet. If anyone could confirm that it may exist, that'd be great, because I am reluctant to report it.

I have a service named `SettingsService` and it has a function called `loadSettings()`. As the name tells, it loads settings. It is supposed to be called before the app loads, which I achieve by adding this to the `providers` part of `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [SettingsService,
                { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                  useFactory: (config: SettingsService) => () => config.loadSettings(), 
                  deps: [SettingsService], 
                  multi: true
                },
```

The bug is that it sometimes works, sometimes not, without even changing either `app.module.ts` or the service itself. Sometimes I just stop the NG Live Development Server, restart it, and the code suddenly doesn't compile. The error message I receive is:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 79:31 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in c:/Node/boltmotor/src/app/app.module.ts
```

At first I tried all kind of tinkering, like removing the lambda function and using a named one, but once I rolled back to the original version, and it suddenly worked. I was able to reproduce it, but it is only randomly happening. Just now I got this error message again, and I fixed it simply by adding a space, deleting it, saving, and as ng-cli recompiled the app, it now worked. Not a single bit of actual code was changed!

I wonder if anyone has some idea about the reason.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this: useFactory: (config: SettingsService) **`=`** () => ...?

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't explain why sometimes it doesn't compile, and other times it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be statically analized. So

```
export function init(config: SettingsService) {
  return () => config.loadSettings();
}

providers: [
  SettingsService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: init,
    deps: [SettingsService],
    multi: true
  }
]
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4647

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this. But why is it that the compiler sometimes accepts a lambda function and sometimes it doesn't.